# How do I take an IPA file and have it install remotely on an iOS device?

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, ipa

The 'traditional' way to install an IPA file is via iTunes.

Its nice the way Test Flight and other tools allow doing this remotely, by downloading from an install link on the web or email.

I tried adding an IPA file to a remote server, and downloading, but Safari informed me "I don't know what to do with this file" (or words to that effect).

Assuming the UDID of the target device is in the provisioning profile, how can I have the file remotely installed on a device.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The search term you're looking for is "over the air" distribution. Try the guide [here](http://shinydevelopment.com/blog/over-the-air-ios-provisioning-and-distribution/)

Comment: Thanks - the step that I was missing was to prepare the plist file.

Answer (score 1):

Enterprise distribution Over The Air
http://help.apple.com/iosdeployment-apps/mac/1.1/?lang=en-us#app43ad871e

Answer (score 1):

In a nutshell, these are the steps:

- in Xcode, use the Product->Archive command to archive your project.
- select the archive in the Organizer window and click the Distribute button
- choose Ad Hoc/Enterprise deployment
- when filling in the fields in the wizard, be sure to enter the URL where the application will be located correctly
- once you've saved the signed app, put the app and the accompanying property list up on your server at the URL you indicated
- create a web page or e-mail that includes a link *to the property list*
- on a device, tap the link to install the app